# Debian Elasticsearch plugins installed but does not show up

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to install plugins (specifically the nori analyzer) on my Elasticsearch in Debian but for some reason, I cannot use them.

I installed the nori analyzer

```
elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-nori
```

and restarted my node by

```
sudo systemctl stop elasticsearch.service
```

and

```
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service
```

When using the nori analyzer, I get a Bad Request response

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 140
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
    "error": {
        "reason": "Unknown analyzer type [nori] for [korean]",
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "reason": "Unknown analyzer type [nori] for [korean]",
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

when I checked the 'elasticsearch-plugin list' command nori did show

```
analysis-nori
```

but when using the 'curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cat/plugins?v' command, I get nothing

```
name    component    version
```

I also checked the node command (curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_nodes) and the 'plugins' section is empty while the 'modules' portion is there but none of its extended plugins have nori.

'curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_nodes/plugin?pretty' returns

```
{
  "_nodes" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "successful" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "nodes" : { }
}
```

I've been trying to debug this for hours now and I can't, for the life of me, figure this out.

Any help is much, much appreciated.

Comment: Which elasticsearch and java versions are you running? Seems like there is some problem with your elasticsearch installation. Perhaps you should try reinstalling it from scratch?

Comment: @John can you provide requested info, so that we can help you

Comment: Thank you for the replies. My java version is 14.0.1 and my elasticsearch version is 7.7.1 The thing when I first installed installed elasticsearch and the nori analyzer before and it worked in creating an index with the analyzer then but when I tried to add an index at a later time, it did not work anymore.